# Finding units of measurement of coefficients in ODE's

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, physics

If we have a question where we have to find the coefficient's units such as K in this case. The actual formula contains more parts but it is simply the derivatives that I am unsure about.
$$K=\frac{dv}{dt}$$

Where $v=ms^{-1}$ (metres per second) and t is time

Do I simply find the derivative of $ms^{-1}$ in respect to s? And whatever units of measurement I am left with are the units of K? ie.

$$\frac{d(ms^{-1})}{ds}$$

$$=m*\frac{d(s^{-1})}{ds}$$

$$=-ms^{-2}$$

Answer (score 1):

No, you just divide by the unit of time. The derivative is defined as a limit of a difference quotient: (velocity difference)/(time difference). This quotient has units (m/s)/s, and taking the limit doesn't change the unit.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not familiar with limits. I just want to know how to do it mathematically. I understand it is simply acceleration, which is $ms^{-2}$ however I want to be able to find it through substituting the units into the derivative. And I don't understand why I am getting $-ms^{-2}$ in this question

Comment: @user88720: OK, to state it simply: If "something" has unit X, then "time derivative of that something" has unit X/time. And if X=distance/time as in your case, then X/time is distance/(time squared).

Comment: Say if I had an equation such as $m\frac{dv}{dt}=mg-kv^2$, where m was mass in kg, v was velocity in $ms^{-1}$, g was gravity in $ms^{-2}$, how would I find the units for K? I re-arranged the formula to have K on the LHS, but when I substitute the units in, they all cancel to zero? Yet I know the answer is actually $\frac{kg}{s}$

Comment: @user88720: You can multiply and divide units, but they can never cancel by addition and subtraction! (Some mass minus some mass equals some mass still; the unit just stays the same.) So here, $mg$ must have the same unit as $kv^2$ (otherwise it wouldn't make sense to subtract), which says that $k$ must have the same unit as $mg/v^2$, which you find by just substituting the known units for $m$, $g$ and $v$, and then multipling and dividing.

Comment: I must be doing something wrong in the re-arranging of it. I'll post my working as a new question